# Pods and nodes Cpu usages in kubernates

Tags: kubernetes

Is Total cpu usages of a node sum up of all pods running in specific nodes.what is the relation between millicpu in cpu cores and % of cpu usages of node.Is request and limit control the cpu usages of pods if so then if a pods cpu usages reach its limit then it will be killed and move other node or continues execution in similar node with maximum limit.

Comment: Can you clarify your question, for example through some interpunction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Millicores is an absolute number (one core divided by 1000). A given node typically has multiple cores, so the relation between the number of millicores and the total percentage varies. For example 1000 millicores (one core) would be 25% on a four core node, but 50% on a node with two cores.

Request determines how much cpu a pod is guaranteed. It will not be scheduled on a node unless the node can deliver that much.

Limit determines how much a pod can get. It will not be killed or moved if it exceeds the limit; it is simply not allowed to exceed the limit.

Comment: So,millicpu doesnot depends upon core( it is depends upon pods requirement) but cpu usage in percentage depends upon core.am i correct.how can move pod if node cpu usage percentage is more?

Comment: CPU usage can be measured in absolute terms (one millicore is 1/1000 of a core) or as a percentage of what is available. Pods always specify requirements and limits in absolute terms, not as percentages. As for moving I don't think it is clear in general when a pod will be moved (there are several alternatives) and as long as the resources it needs (required) are met why should it be moved?

Comment: If pod reaches its limit then its performance will not be good(if it wants more resource to continue) at that condition how can i move?can we mention network band width as a resource like cpu and memory in yaml file?